# how can i achieve setter method in the object variable?? please explain

Tags: java, getter-setter

how can i access beginX & beginY to setBeginX & setBeginY.can i use setX() method for retrieving beginX & beginY

```
public class Line {
   private Point begin;    
   private Point end;

   public Line (Point begin, Point end) {  
      this.begin = begin;
      this.end=end;
   }
   public Line (int beginX, int beginY, int endX, int endY) {
      begin = new Point(beginX, beginY);  
      end =new Point(endX,endY);
   }

   public void setBeginX(int beginX) { 
    // how can i set beginX here.
   }
   public void setBeginY(int beginY) {
   // how can i set beginY here.
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Checking the API for Point (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) you can see that there is no setX() or setY() but there is:

> setLocation(int x, int y)
>
> Changes the point to have the specified
>   location. This method is included for completeness, to parallel the
>   setLocation method of Component. Its behavior is identical with
>   move(int, int).

The coordinates x and y are also public, meaning you could access them directly. You could technically do:

```
public void setBeginX(int beginX) { 
  this.begin.setLocation(beginX, this.begin.getY());
}
```

I would however recommend you change your own API perhaps to allow you to set both x and y at the same time.

If you are actually asking "how can I set beginX variable passed to the constructor", you can't without making it a member variable.